# Recording outgoing calls [UCMA, S4B]

Tags: c#, .net, ucma, skype-for-business

We have skype-for-business server installed and I need to record outgoing calls that go through it. I downloaded the SDK and got familiar with the recorder example, everything works. However, we use native skype for business app, so I have to modify the server environment somehow. Creating client plugin is not an option here.
What is the best option for me? Reroute all calls via MSPL script to my UCMA application? Any clues on how the script should look like? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you are saying is that:

1. The recorder example is recording from THE destination endpoint, there is no way in UCMA to record a call where it's NOT the destination endpoint.
2. You may think you can use the B2BCall in UCMA, but the B2BCall is a medialess setup. i.e. the media does not go through the UCMA application so you can't record.

The only way I can see to do what you want is to turn all outgoing calls into conference calls and then you can bring in the UCMA recording endpoint and record the call.

This has the downside that depending on your volume, it may increase the server requirements to run the lyunc conference servers.

It may be fine if you only want to pick on very specific calls.

So Lync doesn't really help you if you want to record arbitrary Lync Calls.

I would guess the better option may be to buy some sort of Lync call recording solution(s).

If you really want to create a call recording solution, you will need to know:
[SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol), [SDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Description_Protocol), [RTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol), [SRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Real-time_Transport_Protocol), [Audio Codecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_codec) and [network sniffing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer)

Having done just that, I know it's a lot of work that has a lot of hidden complexities.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I already managed to solve this. I created MSPL script that redirects INVITE SIP messages with type='audio' from the endpoints I need to record to my application endpoint. Then I schedule and create new conference and start recording.